# Chef Recipe to create template with nested data

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to create a chef recipe for my Amazon OpsWorks stack. I'd like to pass custom JSON data into the stack, and have the recipe create an .ini file for use with PHP's parse_ini_file() command.

## What I Have Working

Currently, I can create a flat .ini file with the following:

### JSON:

```
{
    "settings_ini": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "width": 10,
        "height": 20
    }
}
```

### The resulting settings.ini file is:

```
quantity = 1
width = 10
height = 20
```

### Chef recipe:

```
template "/my/path/here/settings.ini" do
    owner  "www_data"
    group  "www_data"
    mode   "0644"
    source "settings.ini.erb"
    variables({
        :settings_ini => node[:settings_ini]
    })
end
```

### Chef template "settings.ini.erb":

```
<% @settings_ini.each do |name, value| -%>
<%= name %> = <%= value %>
<% end -%>
```

## What I'm Trying to Make Work

I'd like to change my JSON data to be this:

```
{
    "settings_ini": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "width": 10,
            "height": 20
        }
    }
}
```

And I want my resulting settings.ini file to be this:

```
quantity = 1

[attributes]
width = 10
height = 20
```

Or, it could also be this:

```
quantity = 1
[attributes]width = 10
[attributes]height = 20
```

I need help modifying my settings.ini.erb template file to use the nested JSON data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function.

Stick this into `libraries/hash_to_ini.rb`:

```
def hash_to_ini(hash, lines = [])
  hash.each do |name, value|
    unless value.is_a? Hash
      lines << "#{name} = #{value}"
    else
      lines << "[#{name}]"
      lines = hash_to_ini(value, lines)
    end
  end
  return lines
end
```

Then in your template:

```
<% hash_to_ini(@settings_ini).each do |line| -%>
<%= line %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. My .ini file is ending up empty.

Comment: I've published a simple cookbook to GitHub demonstrating this technique: https://github.com/cassianoleal/cookbook-ini_file

If you have Vagrant, clone it and `vagrant up`. You'll find the `/tmp/settings.ini` file with the proper contents.

It might give you pointers to find the issue in your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a second `each` loop?

```
<% @settings_ini.each do |section, data| -%>
[<%= section %>]
<% data.each do |name, value| -%>
<%= name %> = <%= value %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

This code is untested.. but I guess it should work.

You could also add some safety like done e.g. [here](https://github.com/cla-rce/chef-rvm_passenger/blob/f52eeae94048f9b1ee80bb0e1eed07d4c90d3439/recipes/nginx.rb#L64-L71) and [here](https://github.com/cla-rce/chef-rvm_passenger/blob/f52eeae94048f9b1ee80bb0e1eed07d4c90d3439/templates/default/passenger_nginx.conf.erb#L4-L8)

Comment: I think this assumes that everything is in a nested section, but it won't work for anything on the "root" level (like "quantity" in my example).